# Active Model Serializer with Namespaced (versioned) Controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, active-model-serializers, rails-api

I am building a rails 5 api with active model serializers to render the JSON objects.  I have structured my controllers as follows using namespacing for versions. I'll show one of my resources to display a song.

**application_controller.rb** (simplified):

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  include ActionController::Serialization
end
```

**songs_controller.rb**:

```
class Api::V1::SongsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_song, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]
  def show
    authorize @song
    render json: { song: @song }
  end
  private
  def song_params
    params.require(:song).permit(:title, :artist, :band_id)
  end
  def set_song
    @song = Song.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

**songs_serializer.rb**

```
class SongSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :title, :band_id
end
```

The song model is not namespaced into `Api::V1`. The song model has a few other attributes like `artist`, `created_at`, and `updated_at` that are not included in the serializer so it is my understanding that it will not be included in the JSON sent to the browser app.

My issue is that my application seems to be completely ignoring the `song_serializer` and is sending JSON that includes all database fields for a song. Any input would be welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

After banging my head for longer than I care to admit, My issue seemed to be in my songs_controller in the way I was rendering the JSON. Instead of

`render json: { song: @song }`

I used 

`render json: @song`

and it now uses my serializer.